# Creating buffer spaces in meters around LineString line in KML using Python

Tags: python, geojson, kml, shapely, geolocation

Any suggestions to create buffer spaces on KML LineString using Python? I tried with few libraries..

```
geojson
shapely
kml2geojson
```

Here, converted KML to GeoJSON and added buffer space on the linestring and output should be polygon

```
import kml2geojson
import json

from shapely.geometry import shape
from geojson import Point, Feature, FeatureCollection, dump

filename = "filekml"
direction = "left"

// numbers in meter
numbers = 5
kml2geojson.main.convert(filename + '.kml', '')
features = []
try:

    with open(filename + '.geojson') as geojson_file:
        data = json.load(geojson_file)
        for feat in data['features']:
            if direction == "left":
                result = shape(feat['geometry']).buffer(numbers, single_sided=True)
            if direction == "right":
                result = shape(feat['geometry']).buffer(-numbers, single_sided=True)
            if direction == "both":
                result = shape(feat['geometry']).buffer(numbers)
            features.append(Feature(geometry=result))
        feature_collection = FeatureCollection(features)
        with open(filename + '.geojson', 'w') as f:
            dump(feature_collection, f)
        f.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Below is the KML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml>
<Document id="root_doc">
<Folder><name>Test</name>
  <Placemark>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
      <MultiGeometry><LineString><coordinates>-93.3367092468336,30.4822077397353 -93.3367001199999,30.482718171</coordinates></LineString></MultiGeometry>
  </Placemark>
</Folder>
</Document></kml>
```

Below is the output (GeoJSON)

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -93.3367,
              30.482718
            ],
            [
              -93.336709,
              30.482208
            ],
            [
              -93.336722,
              30.482208
            ],
            [
              -93.336713,
              30.482718
            ],
            [
              -93.3367,
              30.482718
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Any suggestions to create buffer spaces of line or points?

Comment: What is the problem, do you get error messages?

Comment: No, I'm not getting any error message., But My actual need is to be created buffer space directly from kml linestring.. instead of         (kml-->geojson-->adding buffer space-->converting geojson to kml)    I want to bypass it like, 
(kml-->adding buffer space--> kml)

-Thank you.!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to buffer a line either side-sided to left or right, or all directions by a distance in meters then [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/) library makes this simple. Once you have the KML converted to GeoJSON, read the GeoJSON file into a GeoDataFrame, reproject the data into a coordinate system with meters as units, perform the buffer, then convert back to WGS84 (EPSG-4326).

```python
import geopandas as gpd

# If want to read from GeoJSON then uncomment next line
#gdf = gpd.read_file('test.geojson')

# if want to read from KML, need to make sure the KML driver is added
gpd.io.file.fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw'
gdf = gpd.read_file('test.kml', driver='KML')

direction = "left"  # left|right|both
width = 5           # buffer width in meters

# first need to reproject your features into a coordinate system with meters as units.
gdf = gdf.to_crs(3857)
if direction == "left":
    gdf['geometry'] = gdf['geometry'].buffer(width, single_sided=True)
elif direction == "right":
    gdf['geometry'] = gdf['geometry'].buffer(-width, single_sided=True)
else:
    gdf['geometry'] = gdf['geometry'].buffer(width)
gdf = gdf.to_crs(4326)  # reproject back to 4326

# save output in new GeoJSON file
gdf.to_file('out.geojson', driver="GeoJSON")
```

To transform point features just need this line, since the side_side argument is not applicable for a point.

```
gdf['geometry'] = gdf['geometry'].buffer(width)
```

If you want to convert the GeoJSON result into KML then you can use the Python code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71116608/543969).

Comment: Hi @CodeMonkey, My actual need is to be created buffer space directly from kml linestring.. instead of (kml-->geojson-->adding buffer space-->converting geojson to kml) I want to bypass it like, (kml-->adding buffer space--> kml) -Thank you.!

Comment: Actually, trying to avoid with geojson.. So that, directly adding buffer space from kml.. Please check the below kml.. need to be added buffer space..

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml>
<Document id="root_doc">
<Folder><name>Test</name>
  <Placemark>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
      <MultiGeometry><LineString><coordinates>-93.3367092468336,30.4822077397353 -93.3367001199999,30.482718171</coordinates></LineString></MultiGeometry>
  </Placemark>
</Folder>
</Document></kml>

Comment: @GokulRaghu if you set driver='KML' then you directly import the KML file with geopandas and add a buffer to the features. It works with your pasted KML above.